# Can someone please tell me why Azure Pipelines does not like this yaml file?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

```yaml
--- 
variables: 
     azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Professional Subscription (237bc9da-22ad-49ea-8411-6cf6a190c18f)'
     RG: ClassroomInTheCloud
jobs:
- job: 1   
  steps:

    - task: AzureCLI@1
      dislayName: 'Azure CLI '
      inputs:
       azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
       scriptLocation: inlineScript
       inlineScript: |
        mkdir $(Pipeline.Workspace)\BlobFile
        az storage blob download --container-name $(containername) --file '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/student.json' --name 'student.json' --connection-string 'VALUE IN HERE'


    - pwsh: |
       cd '/home/vsts/work/1/s/'
       ls
       $armOutput = Get-Content '/home/vsts/work/1/s/student.json' | convertfrom-json
       $studentvalue = $armOutput.studentvalue 
       $type = $armOutput.type
       Write-Host "The value of [$studentvalue] is [$type]"
       Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$studentvalue;]$type"
       Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$studentvalue;isOutput=true]$studentvalue"
       Write-Output "The Value of studentvalue is [$studentvalue]"
      name: setvarStep

    - script: | 
        echo $(studentvalue)

- job: 2
  displayName: Create Web App 
  dependsOn: 1
  variables:
   webappname: $[studentvalue]

   steps: 
     - task: AzureWebApp@1
       inputs:
       azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
       resourceGroupName: $(RG)
       appName: $(webappname)
       package: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)**/*.csproj

     - task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
       displayName: Azure App Service Settings
       inputs:
       azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
       appName: $(webappname)
   # To deploy the settings on a slot, provide slot name as below. By default, the settings would be applied to the actual Web App (Production slot)
   # slotName: staging
       appSettings: |
        [
           {
              "name": "DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL",
              "value": "VALUEINHERE",
              "slotSetting": false
           },
           {
              "name": "DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBRETENTIONINDAYS",
              "value": "365",
              "slotSetting": false
           },
           {
              "name": "OEM",
              "value": "netsupport",
              "slotSetting": false
           },
           {
              "name": "SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH",
              "value": "d:\\home\\respository",
              "slotSetting": false
           },
           {
              "name": "VIDEO_CLIENT_URL",
              "value": "https://signal-uks.classroom.cloud",
              "slotSetting": false
           },
           {
              "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "10.15.2",
              "slotSetting": false
           }
        ]
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting the following errors when putting this YAML file in the pipeline?

```
Line 14, Col 7: Unexpected Value Display Name
Line 45, Col 6: A sequence was not expected
```

Comment: I'd probably start by reworking your indentation. Then, since you're showing a snippet of your YAML, I'd highlight the specific lines that it's complaining about, as there are no line numbers in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please firstly review this doc: [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) and [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable), following is the sample yaml of setting a multi-job output variable.

```
jobs:
# Set an output variable from job A
- job: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
  - powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isOutput=true]this is the value"
    name: setvarStep
  - script: echo $(setvarStep.myOutputVar)
    name: echovar

# Map the variable into job B
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'
  variables:
    myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myOutputVar'] ]  # map in the variable
                                                                          # remember, expressions require single quotes
  steps:
  - script: echo $(myVarFromJobA)
    name: echovar
```

Thus the following snippet of yaml should be correct syntax for your reference.

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables: 
  azureSubscription: 'subscription here'
  RG: 'WClassroomInTheCloud'

jobs:
- job: job1   
  steps:
  - task: AzureCLI@1
    displayName: 'Azure CLI '
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        mkdir $(Pipeline.Workspace)\BlobFile
        az storage blob download --container-name $(containername) --file '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/student.json' --name 'student.json' --connection-string 'VALUE IN HERE'

  - pwsh: |
      cd '/home/vsts/work/1/s/'
      ls
      $armOutput = Get-Content '/home/vsts/work/1/s/student.json' | convertfrom-json
      $student = $armOutput.studentvalue #use student not studentvalue
      $type = $armOutput.type
      Write-Host "The value of [$student] is [$type]"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=studentvalue;isOutput=true]$student" #use studentvalue not $studentvalue
    name: setvarStep

  - script: echo $(setvarStep.studentvalue)
    name: echovar

- job: job2
  displayName: Create Web App 
  dependsOn: job1
  variables:
    webappname: $[ dependencies.job1.outputs['setvarStep.studentvalue'] ]

  steps: 
  
  - task: AzureWebApp@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
      appType: 'webApp'
      resourceGroupName: $(RG)
      appName: $(webappname)
      package: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)**/*.csproj

  - task: AzureAppServiceSettings@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
      appName: $(webappname)
      resourceGroupName: $(RG)
      # To deploy the settings on a slot, provide slot name as below. By default, the settings would be applied to the actual Web App (Production slot)
      # slotName: staging
      appSettings: |
        {
          "name": "DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL",
          "value": "VALUEINHERE",
          "slotSetting": false
        },
        {
          "name": "DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBRETENTIONINDAYS",
          "value": "365",
          "slotSetting": false
        },
        {
          "name": "OEM",
          "value": "netsupport",
          "slotSetting": false
        },
        {
          "name": "SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH",
          "value": "d:\\home\\respository",
          "slotSetting": false
        },
        {
          "name": "VIDEO_CLIENT_URL",
          "value": "https://signal-uks.classroom.cloud",
          "slotSetting": false
        },
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
          "value": "10.15.2",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I can now see where I was going wrong and I just couldn't get my head round the passing the variable definition it now makes sense to me. I did read those two articles and many more, but now ive seen your write up a big aha moment has happened, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The second error is because `steps` at line 40 is at the level of `webappname` when it should be at the level of `variables`. Generally you shouldn't use single-space indentation to avoid such errors.

I am not sure about the first error but try writing `displayName` instead of `dislayName` on line 10.